# Automatic Data Loading in MVC 3 App

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Ok, I have a page where the data is loaded dynamically from a dropdown using a jquery/ajax load function. This allows a partial view to load dynamically displaying a grid with all the data once the dropdown selection is altered.

The problem with this is that when the page loads the first time, so data is loaded, which signifies that no id selection is being sent to the jquery load function.  I attempted to remedy this by adding a load function for the dropdownlist itself, so when it is loaded, it will reload the data view, but to no avail. I figure it is because the control loads before data is loaded in it. But I am at a loss to what to do. Here is the code I have so far.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("SessionsPartial", "Sessions")',
            data: 'id=' + $("#ScheduleTypeId").value,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#SessionData').fadeOut().html(data).fadeIn();
            }
        });
     $(function () {
    $("#ScheduleTypeId").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("SessionsPartial", "Sessions")',
            data: 'id=' + this.value,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#SessionData').fadeOut().html(data).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
          });

    $(function() {
        $("#ScheduleTypeId").load(function() {
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("SessionsPartial", "Sessions")',
                    data: 'id=' + this.value,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#SessionData').fadeOut().html(data).fadeIn();
                    }
                });
        });
    });
 });
```

As I said, the last part with the load part is what I just added, so feel free to critique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the ajax function was indeed calling the action function that loads the data into the partial, but it was sending the id of the model on the initial load as opposed to the id of the dropdown, so the data was loading empty.

I remedied that by checking if the value was 0 then forcing it to load with the id of the item that will be first at any rate. worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

When the page is loaded the first time you don't really need to perform an AJAX call to load the data. You could simply include the partial that contains the grid:

```
<div id="SessionData">
    @Html.Partial("SessionsPartial")
</div>
```

and then only subscribe to the `.change()` event of the dropdown to refresh the partial:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#ScheduleTypeId').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("SessionsPartial", "Sessions")',
            cache: false,
            data: { id: $(this).val() },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#SessionData').fadeOut().html(data).fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```